# Flask: session max size too small

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask

I'm building a data analysis Flask application which takes a ton of user inputs, performs some calculations then projects the results to various web pages. I'm using a pandas Dataframe to store the inputs and perform the calculations. Then I convert the DF to a dictionary and store that in the session object.

I'm having problems due to the fact that the session object can only hold ~4k bytes. Several pages read the data so I need a means to pass this large amount of data (~5k-50k) from one request to another (which the session object does perfectly but for smaller memory sizes).

Can I set the storage limit higher for the session object (I imagine I can't as 4k is the limit for a cookie and the session object is a cookie)? Or is there something else I should do here (store the dict in a database, etc.)?

EDIT:

I'm thinking a viable alternative would be to grab the data from the database (mongodb in my case), store it in a local variable and pass that variable to the template directly. Are there negatives to this? And is there a limit on how much memory I can pass directory to a template? See example below:

```
@app.route('/results')
def results():
    # get data I need from database (~5k-50k bytes)
    data = mongo.db[collection_name].find_one({'key': 'query'})
    # pass directory to template (instead of storing in session object)
    return render_template('results_page.html', data=data)
```

Comment: The limit is related to HTTP cookies. Your options are: 1) store in database 2) user a server side caching system like redis. Sticking to a database is usually less of a headache. For something in that size you should be able to get great performance whatever you choose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah this definitely sounds like a case for server-side sessions.
There are [code snippets on the official site](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/category/sessions/) for the most popular databases.

These shouldn't be hard to migrate to since they use the same `SessionMixin` interface as the cookie session system.

An even easier approach could be to use [Flask-KVSession](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-KVSession/), which claims that

> Integration with Flask is seamless, once the extension is loaded for a Flask application, it transparently replaces Flask’s own Session management. Any application working with sessions should work the same with Flask-KVSession

Comment: Thanks! I also found [Flask-Sessions](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) which helps with server-side sessions. I have one more question, see edit above.

Comment: That seems fine. I mean the data isn't copied when it's sent to the jinja templating engine, just a reference to the same piece of memory. Then the question is - is 50kb too big for an HTML page? Nope, seems fine to me. An alternative would be to serve json through an API endpoint and have your page dynamically load it, but that's probably not necessary here.

Comment: Sounds good. Any idea how much data is too much for an HTML page?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I assume that's limited by server memory. On the browser side, lag seems to arise when you send over more than 4MB of JSON - see [How big is too big for JSON?](http://josh.zeigler.us/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/)

Comment: flask kvsession is stalled, use flask-sessions instead. But be honest if you have large object need to be stored per session, it is better to avoid ser/deser completely so maybe caching is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

[Flask-Session](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) adds support to Server-side Session.

Here is how you can start Flask-Session (extracted from the [official documentation](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask.ext.session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
# Check Configuration section for more details
SESSION_TYPE = 'redis'
app.config.from_object(__name__)
Session(app)

@app.route('/set/')
def set():
    session['key'] = 'value'
    return 'ok'

@app.route('/get/')
def get():
    return session.get('key', 'not set')
```

Regarding the size limit on rendering templates, the [official Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.render_template) has no mention of this.
I don't really believe there is any size limit actually.

If there is any limitation, that might be on [Jinja's](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/) side.